# How having both Numeric keyboard and string format "n0" on textbox of WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have providing a Textbox on WPF

```
<TextBox TextChanged="txtChange"   PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationTextBox" />
```

And for each event I have:

```
 private void NumberValidationTextBox(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex1 = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
            e.Handled = regex1.IsMatch(e.Text);
        }

        private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            double number = double.Parse(txt.Text.Replace(",", ""));
           txt.Text= number.ToString("n0");
           txt.Focus();

           txt.Select(txt.Text.Length, 0);
        }
```

It's works fine, I have numbers and "," for string format of "000,000,000"

But during the code I have changing selector of textbox, so this code have problems. Let me to know how could I provide both

Comment: If I'm understanding your questio correct, which I'm not sure I am, you are trying to select all the text? Try `txtSelect.SelectAll()` instead.  It *might* have to be sent to the `Dispatcher` to make sure it happens after any bindings, if so, try this `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate()
            {
                txtSelect.SelectAll();
            });`

Comment: @BradleyUffner When I have using "n0" format. focuse goes to first place of textbox, so when user try to type more, number goes to be wrong , I have adding  txt.Select(txt.Text.Length, 0); to have focus at end of numbers. But on case of user try to edit part of numbers, this focus changing makes problems

Comment: Ahh, now I understand the problem. Have you considered using the `MaskedTextBox` from the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/MaskedTextBox)?  It can do all that and more.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I can't use such a thing, because I try to let user to type "Price", price can be with any length